# Where is Initialization code in this Leetcode solution for Two Sum

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm not asking about this line ->
`Dictionary<int, int> resultDictionary = new();`
according to my knowledge this line initialize an empty Dictionary,
so where does the data that the TryGetValue Method checks against come from?
in this line ->
`if (resultDictionary.TryGetValue(secondNumber, out int index))`

**The following code contains Dictionary declaration but what is wondering me is the absence of populating Dictionary with data.
Can anyone explain what's going on here?**

```
public class Solution {
    public int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target) 
    {
        //Declarations
            int arrayLength = nums.Length;
            Dictionary<int, int> resultDictionary = new();
            
            //Validations
            if (nums == null || arrayLength < 2)
            {
                return Array.Empty<int>();
            }

            //Logic
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
            {
                int firstNumber = nums[i];
                int secondNumber = target - firstNumber;
                
                if (resultDictionary.TryGetValue(secondNumber, out int index))
                {
                    
                    
                    return new[] { index, i };
                }

                //resultDictionary.Add(firstNumber, i);
                resultDictionary[firstNumber] = i;
                //Console.Write(resultDictionary[firstNumber]);
            }

            return Array.Empty<int>(); 
        
    }
}
```

Comment: It says `= new()`. It's shorthand syntax from C# 9: target-typed new expressions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new

Comment: Please re-read [mre] guidance on posting code to make your future questions better. In particular 99% of code in this post is unrelated to the question you have (one single line `Dictionary<int, int> resultDictionary = new();` would be enough). Also there is no relation between neither Leetcode nor Two Sum problem which are mentioned in the title and question you have - coming up with question titles that actually relate to the question is a skill that would make questions better too.

Comment: I'm not asking about this line -> Dictionary<int, int> resultDictionary = new();
according to my knowledge this line initialize an empty Dictionary,
so where does the data that the TryGetValue Method checks against come from?
 in this line -> if (resultDictionary.TryGetValue(secondNumber, out int index))

Comment: Thank you all for your participation,
The point here is that Dictionary obj has been declared but not initialized by data!!

Answer (score 0):

The code uses a C# version 9 language feature, called *target-typed new*. You can have more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new)